# Tensorflow - keras - Shape errors with 'strided_slice' (used resized MNIST dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am going to make some GAN-Model Tester using tf.keras with MNIST hand-writed digits dataset. Because my model is going to be used in 128x128 images, I resized MNIST dataset to 128x128x1. but, the program makes some errors, that I never seen.

```
(x_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
x_train = tf.image.resize_images(x_train, [128, 128])

idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], batch_size)  # picks some data, count is batch_size=32.
imgs = x_train[idx]  # This line made errors
```

The last line made two errors:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_1' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [60000,128,128,1], [1,32], [1,32], [1].

and,

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'strided_slice_1' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [60000,128,128,1], [1,32], [1,32], [1].

I think the number '32' means batch_size(=32).

I tried to find about this error, but I couldn't find like this error.

I don't have any ideas to solve this problems (because I started to use keras a week ago, before I used pytorch).

Comment: what is (1,32), 32 isn't the batch size? Please print(idx).

Comment: idx is the batch_size-sized list with random integer values. it is used at picking up 32 random MNIST data. example: [35904 26046 21148 28562 56414 31930 44948 53721  2118 30226  6292 57618
 39161 46354  9053 46421 44620 36931  8266 48759 42023 40365 33027 13278
 57609  3804 57904  4377  3517 30322 16445 47825]

Comment: I think your idx if you printed it would be of shape (1,32) from the error message, that's why I asked you to print it.

Comment: The result of print(idx) is the example above, so I printed idx.shape: (32,).

Comment: you wrote: imgs = x_train[idx] # This line made errors, not print(idx)

Comment: I tried debug, breakpointed at last error-causing line. I approached that x_train's value was Tensor("ResizeBilinear:0", shape=(60000, 128, 128, 1), dtype=float32). Is this cause problems(that x_train is not ndarray, the tensor) to slice some random data?

Comment: wait a bit I will add a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have more issue with your code above, but the primer cause of error is that tensorflow doesn't  support the numpy type advanced slicing.
Actually the error message is because tensorflow try to align your input array in his [strided-slices](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice):

An example for the strided-slices:

> foo[5:,:,:3] on a 7x8x9 tensor is equivalent to foo[5:7,0:8,0:3].
>   foo[::-1] reverses a tensor with shape 8.

Unfortunately only basic type indexing is available in Tensorflow currently. Advanced type indexing is under development.

The secondary problem, that your resizing was not proper.
Tensorflow assumes a 3D or 4D input. You tried to pass a 2D image to `tf.image.resize_images(), which doesn't return the required new image dimensions. So we have to reshape the raw images like this:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape((-1, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], 1))
```

only then we can pass them to:

```
`x_train = tf.image.resize_images(x_train, [128, 128])
```

It will return then the proper dimensions:

```
print(x_train.shape)
```

**Out:**

```
(60000, 128, 128, 1)
```

So summarizing the whole solution, currently you can do it as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 32

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape((-1, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
x_train = tf.image.resize_images(x_train, [128, 128])

idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], batch_size)

imgs = [x_train[i,:,:,:] for i in idx]
```

which is a pretty messy "solution".

**Other, actually a real solution with rearrange the original code we can achieve what we aimed to as a workaround to the tensorflow indexing issue:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 32

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
idx = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], batch_size)
x_train = x_train[idx]

x_train = x_train.reshape((-1, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_train = tf.image.resize_images(x_train, [128, 128])

print(x_train.shape)
```

**Out:**

```
(32, 128, 128, 1)
```

That's it!

Alternatively instead of tf.image.resize_images() you can use an additional image tools like [skimage.transform.resize()](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html) from [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) which returns numpy array type data.

Comment: I didn't know about the development of tensorflow. I got the idea to fix these problems! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code worked successfully. Now I only have to fix my original codes' structure. thanks for helping me.